# How to override registration form message

Tags: status-messages

I should override registration form message "Registration successful. You are now logged in." with String Overrides module it does not work, because new text is long and every line with other style, it is in Drupal 7
I try to do it in template.php , but no my code is working.
Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0):

You can check this message in hook_init it's working for me please try this code.

```
function custom_init() {
 if (!empty($_SESSION['messages']['status'])) {
  $message_text_to_remove = "Registration successful. You are now logged in.";
  $key = array_search($message_text_to_remove, $_SESSION['messages']['status']);
   if ($key !== FALSE) {
      $_SESSION['messages']['status'][$key] = t('Greta Now your message changed');
    }
  }
 }
```

Thankyou

Comment: Thank you very much. I used this code in template.php , but nothing have changed (

Comment: Try this in custom module.It's working if you need i will create video for you.

Comment: Pankaj Thank you very much. I do not want to waste your time , I understood about module )

Comment: Glad to help you.

Comment: Pankaj, I override it , everything is ok. Just want to know , how can I change message show time?

Comment: Unable to understand what do you want to change message or time .

Comment: I changed the message , Now I want to change message show time

Answer (score 0):

Maybe someone will need this, I put it in template.php

```
function THEME_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
 if($form_id == 'user_register_form') {
   $form['account']['mail']['#attributes'] = array('placeholder'=> array(t('E-mail')));
      $form['account']['name']['#prefix'] = '<div id="' . $form_id . '">';
      $form['account']['name']['#prefix']  = '<h5 class="title">'.t('Create account').'</h5>';
      $form['actions']['submit']['#suffix'] = '<span class="or">or</span><a href="'.$base_path.'/user/simple-fb-connect" class="fb_simple">CONTINUE WITH FACEBOOK</a>'.'<div class="back-to-login clearfix"><p>Already have an account?</p>' .  '<a href="/user/login" class="use-ajax login-account" data-dialog="true">LOGIN</a>';
      $form['actions']['submit']['#suffix'] .= '</div>';
       drupal_set_message(' Your message');
   }
}
```